# Выдаёт ошибку при попытке забиндить enter на кнопку в Python Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Текст ошибки:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Sem\Desktop\Foxford\Python\hh.pyw", line 39, in btnReturn
    Btn()
TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable
```

Кнопка:

```
Btn = Button(window, text="Рассчитать", command=clicked)  
Btn.grid(column=0, row=10)
```

То как я пытаюсь забиндить:

```
def btnReturn(e):
    Btn()

window.bind('<Return>', btnReturn)
```

Как исправить ошибку, или может быть можно как-то обойти этот способ бинда?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка `TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable` переводится примерно так: "Объект типа Button не вызываемый". Т.е. вы пытаетесь вызвать кнопку как функцию, а для кнопок такая возможность не предусмотрена (не реализован метод `__call__`), отсюда ошибка.

Если нужно выполнить то же действие, что и при нажатии кнопки, вызовите привязанную к кнопке функцию (у вас это `clicked`):

```
def clicked():
     print('Hello!')

Btn = Button(window, text="Рассчитать", command=clicked)  
Btn.grid(column=0, row=10)

def btnReturn(e):
    clicked()

window.bind('<Return>', btnReturn)
```